# Change the target of a hyperlink while clicked and continue to url with new update target

Tags: jquery

That is my link:

```
<a class="MyLinks" target="_self" href="xxx" >My site</a>
```

That is My jquery code:

```
$(document).on("click", '.MyLinks', function (e) {     
       e.originalEvent.currentTarget.target = "_blank";                    
  });
```

I hit the click event but the link does not open in a new tab.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open that link in a new tab without changing the HTML you need to cancel the event that was raised using `preventDefault()` then call `window.open()`, like this:

```
$(document).on("click", '.MyLinks', e => {     
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open(e.target.href); 
});
```

If you can change the HTML then the easiest way to do what you need is to set the `target` to `_blank`:

```html
<a class="MyLinks" target="_blank" href="xxx">My site</a>
```

Comment: You said "without changing the html" BUT THAT IS my question... how to open the clicked link in a new tab...ok its this:  window.open(e.target.href, "_blank"); ah its by default a new tab LOL

Comment: If you can change the HTML then use `target="_blank"`. I updated the answer for the sake of completeness

Comment: I need to do it dynamically, thanks for the first solution ;-)

Comment: No problem, glad to help